# C# UWP - Can't add reference to project in same solution

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I need to write a UI for an API utility that I need to use.  I have created a new Universal Windows App for the UI, added the API utility project to the solution and now need to reference the API utility from the UWP project - but I just get 'Unable to add a reference to project 'XXX'.

If I create a Windows Forms Application or a console project and add that to the solution, I can do the referencing, no probs.

What is it about UWP that I don't understand?

Comment: such an obvious thing and nobody knows. I just created a test app and get the same problem.

Comment: Yes I have this referencing a .net core2 project from a UWP project, but everything works fine regarding using the .net namespace from the uwp. It looks like a bug for Microsoft to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the project that you are trying to reference, make sure the `TargetFrameworks` moniker doesn't contain `.NET Core` or `.NET Framework`.

1. Right mouse button click on the project you are referencing.
2. Edit Project File
3. Find `<TargetFrameworks>`
4. Remove the targets you don't need. For UWP you may leave only the .NET Standard 2.0 target:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a portable class library for your API utility.

See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe PCL's are deprecated as of .NET standard 2.0

Comment: Things have changed. Now Microsoft doesn't recommend it. The link says: `Because Portable Class Library projects target only a very specific subset of .NET implementations, we strongly discourage their use in new application development. The recommended replacement is a .NET Standard library, which targets all .NET implementations that support a specific version of the .NET Standard. For more information, see .NET Standard.`

Answer (score 2):

When coding UWP , to build library that can be referenced by a same-solution UI UWP project I need to use a specific library project template  (e.g.: by doing  Add new Project | Windows | Class Library (Universal Windows)) , that's what worked for me ( I assume you have  UWP SDK installed ) so if you have your .dll source  maybe you should try to recompile it using that project format. Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll give it a go when I have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to provide reference to c# projects.

Select project -> Right click References -> Add reference
 1. via .dll : Browse for Assemblies(.dll files) and select your desired file -> OK
 2. via .csproj : Select Projects/Shared Projects from left menu -> browse for the .csproj files (Note: choose file-filter as 'All files' to make them visible) -> OK

Comment: Not with UWP there isn't... or not like this anyway. Give it a go if you don't believe me.

Answer (score -2):

When adding the Test Project, instead of going to "Test" and selecting "Unit Test Project (.Net Framework)"…
Go to "Windows Universal" and select "Unit Test App (Universal Windows)"

If you select this project, then you will be able to add a reference to your UWP project.

Comment: Exactly where in my question do I mention Test project?